# HTMl CSS Dropdown Nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I have a navigation menu that works well and looks good.

The HTML for the menu is:

```
<div id="menubar">
    <div id="welcome">
        <h1><a href="#">Cedars Hair <span>Academy</span></a></h1>
    </div><!--close welcome-->
    <div id="menu_items">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">The Salon</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">The Staff</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--close menu-->
</div><!--close menubar-->
```

But I want to change it so it is something like:

```
<li><a href="#">The Salon</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Hair Cut</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So under the salon, a drop down menu would come up with 'Hair Cut'.

I know this is possible with CSS, but the problem is I have a lot of CSS with the divs shown above (menubar, welcome, menu_items etc). Do you know the most simplest way to make a simple dropdown?

Comment: Plenty tutorials online. One really easy: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way in a nutshell:

https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/2jd9uvx0/

1. hide lists inside other lists
2. upon hovering list elements, show the child lists

```css
ul ul {
    display:none;
    display:absolute;
    bottom:-100%;
}
li{
    position:relative;
}
li:hover>ul {
    display:table;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">The Salon</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hair Cut</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The rest is styling and up to preferences. >ou can combine this with animations/transitions, and position the elements as you like. But since you asked for the simplest way: I would say this is it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Jquery UI?
https://jqueryui.com/menu/

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).menu();
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added the sub menu using `li:hover`

Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/gkdj6y5x/